# How to set the box width same as the screen width?

Tags: html, css

now i am coding for a mobile page with **HTML,CSS**.
I want to set **a box**,which have a background-color for more beautiful and some text to show the infomation.
But when I set the width is 100%,the box's width is **not the same as** the screen's width.And it is not what I want.
How can I solve it in css?

I have tried the "width:100%",but it failed.
my CSS is:

```
div
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 105px;
    left: 0;
    height: 47px;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 47px;
    background-color: rgba(255,108,108,0.5);
}
```

**HTML is:**

```
<div><span>my number:<span><span>517014910</span></div>
```

Comment: Is this what you want.I understood from ypour question that you want to make your page/div fullscreen.Is it ?.If yes :http://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/fK3vC/

Comment: I have tried the "width:100%",but it failed.my CSS is:div{position: absolute;top: 105px;left: 0;height: 47px;width: 100%;line-height: 47px;background-color: rgba(255,108,108,0.5);}.HTML is:<div><span>my number:<span><span>517014910</span></div>

Comment: Post your html in the question in a formatted manner

Comment: @Jasmin:Did you check the fiddle i had posted:[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/fK3vC/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/H79gp/)

use `width : 100%`

```
div{position: absolute;top: 105px;left: 0;height: 47px;width: 100%;line-height: 47px;background-color: rgba(255,108,108,0.5);}
```

Comment: Thanks!It works.At first I ignored setting the parent div 100% width.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the box sizing property. It allows you to define certain elements to fit an area in a certain way.The border-box value makes the final rendered box the declared width, and any border and padding cut inside the box. Try implementing the following example on your case. Here it refers to textarea, but you could try implementing it on other element containing your text:

```
textarea { 
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add "left:0;right:0;" since you're already in absolute positioning ?

See fiddle there : http://jsfiddle.net/3ZBXV/

```
<div style="position:absolute;...;left:0;right:0;" />
```